# Derivative rule for a tangent vector space in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have been trying to prove that, letting $M^2$ be a Riemannian manifold and $X,Y$ two differentiable vector fields on a neighborhood $U$ of $p \in M$, then for any tangent vector $v \in T_p M$ the derivative rule:
$v \langle X,Y \rangle = \langle \nabla_v X, Y \rangle + \langle X, \nabla_v Y \rangle$
holds.

But to be honest, I'm having troubles even understanding why $v \langle X,Y \rangle$ is a derivative... and of course, I'm far far away of proving this derivative rule... any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That holds if $\nabla$ preserves the metric $g = \langle {}\cdot{},{}\cdot{}\rangle$, i.e. $\nabla g = 0$ (for example, if $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection): in general if $X,Y,Z$ are vector fields on $M$ you have 
$$\nabla g(X,Y,Z) := (\nabla_X g)(Y,Z)= X(g(Y,Z))-g(\nabla_X Y,Z)-g(Y,\nabla_X Z),$$
so you obtain your formula when $\nabla g = 0$.

If $X$ is a vector field on $M$ and $f$ is a function defined around a point $p$, then $X_p(f)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ along the direction given by $X_p$. So, with your notation: $f\colon p \mapsto \langle X,Y \rangle_p$ is a function of $p$. Thus $\nu_p(f)=\nu_p(\langle X,Y \rangle)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ along the direction given by $\nu_p$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand the notation of $v_p(\langle X, Y \rangle)$. I also understand that given your expression for $\bigtriangledown_g(X,Y,Z)$, my equation holds if $\bigtriangledown_g = 0$... However, I'm not sure how to came out with your expression for $\bigtriangledown_g(X,Y,Z)$. Is it the deffinition?

Comment: I would say it depends on what you already know. I have seen some articles, and have had a course, where it was taken as a definition, whereas in some other places it is proved. I think a very good place to see why that formula crops up is the book 'A course of Differential geometry and topology' by Mishchenko and Fomenko. With two simple axioms you can find a general local expression for $\nabla T$, where $T$ is any tensor. You can just specialise to the case where $T$ is a 2-covariant tensor, and then try to find the intrinsic form of $\nabla T$.

Comment: Another reference for this formula could be 'Foundations of Differential Geometry' by Kobayashi and Nomizu. Here I would say the formalism is more intrinsic in general.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much again! I will check those references out.